# IBM MQ publish/subscribe send message to one subscriber

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I want to build a publish/subscribe program to compute matrix manipulation on a cluster.

When a publisher send a message to a topic, message copies to all subscribers.

I want a copy of message send to one subscriber and the message deletes and not send to other subscribers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1. Make an administrative subscription and have all subscribers read messages off the queue to which the subscription points.
2. Use MQ V8.0, the new JMS 2.0 interface, and the [Shared Subscription](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q119140_.htm) feature.

Note that in both of these cases, all subscribers are connected to the same queue manager.  Although Pub/Sub creates a single logical message, when it is broadcast to other queue managers it becomes multiple physical messages and their consumption by subscribers is not coordinated across the network.

Answer (score 0):

Use a queue, not a topic. Topics are designed for one-to-many publication, queues allow multiple listeners but each message is delivered to only one listener.

Comment: Actually, as of JMS 2.0, the functionality OP is inquiring about is part of the specification and is called a  [shared subscription](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms2messaging-1954190.html).  That said, it's a valid pattern and prior to JMS 2.0 people achieved it by directing multiple instances of the app to a queue into which a subscription delivered topic messages. In fact, the new feature exists *because* it is such a common pattern.